# Counting Problems with conditions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

A stock-selection committee of 4 is to be selected from an investment club of 25 people. How many different committees are possible under each of the following conditions?

1. One person is to chair the committee; the others are to be general members.
2. There is no distinction whatever among the members of the committee
3. One person is to chair the committee, another is in charge of suggesting stocks, the third is in charge of writing up a report on each stock suggested and the fourth is to act as treasurer.

For 1:This would be a permutation, in the form of (25/3)?

For 2: This would be combination, in the form (25/4)?

For 3: No idea.

Answer (score 2):

The last ones the easiest.

3) 25 choices for chairman, 24 for stock suggester, etc. $= 25\times 24\cdots \times22 = \frac{25!}{21!}$

2) The second one is the second easiest.  25 choose 4.  ${25 \choose 4} = \dfrac{25!}{21!4!}$

1)  There are 25 choices for chairmen.  The rest are just 24 choose 3.  Answer is $25{24 \choose 3} = 25\dfrac{24!}{21!3!}$

Answer (score 0):

$1. C(25,1)*C(25,3) $ Choose one to be head, and three indistinguishable

$2. C(25,4)$ Choose 4 indistinguishable people

$3. 25*24*23*22 $ 4 distinguishable people

I think

Comment: You seem to have two typoes.  C(25, 1) not C(125, 1).  And 25\*24\*23\*22.

Answer (score 0):

1: 25! / (4! (25-4)!)=12650, 4! / (1! (4-1)!)= 4, 12650*4= 50,600

2: 25! /(4! (25-4)!)= 12650

Comment: You should include your attempts at the solutions in your question.  This will demonstrate that you have thought about the question yourself and give readers of your question an opportunity to provide feedback on your attempts.  Your second answer is correct.  For the first problem, see the answer provided by fleablood.

Comment: I couldn't add a comment, didnt know how